# Проблема с выполнением кода из-за } приходится писать код несколько раз. Как избежать этого?

Tags: php

Вот, к примеру, код:

```
if (
preg_match("/^все/", $pere)
) {
$q = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `daba` where table='все' limit 0,2";
$r = mysql_query("$q;") or die("Что-то не так.");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_object($re))
print_r($r->opisanie);
}
if (
$a == $b
) {
$q = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `daba` where table='все' limit 0,2";
$r = mysql_query("$q;") or die("Что-то не так.");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_object($re))
print_r($r->opisanie);
}
```

Вариант:

```
if (
preg_math("/^все/, $pere) &&
$a == $b
)
```

И вариант:

```
if ( ( preg_match("/^все/", $pere) ) || ( $a == $b ) ) {
  $sql = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `daba` where `table`='все' limit 0,2;";
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("Что-то не так.");
  while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($res) ) echo $row->opisanie;
}
```

Не подходит.

Как избежать повторения выполнения кода?

**UPD**: проблема исчерпана, переделал код...

Comment: <code><pre>
if (preg_match("/^все/", $pere)) show();
if ($a == $b) show();

function show() {
    $sql = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `daba` where `table`='все' limit 0,2;";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("Что-то не так.");
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($res) ) echo $row->opisanie;
}
</code></pre>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
if ( ( preg_match("/^все/", $pere) ) || ( $a == $b ) ) {
  $sql = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `daba` where `table`='все' limit 0,2;";
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("Что-то не так.");
  while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($res) ) echo $row->opisanie;
}
```

Comment: такой вариант тоже не подходит...
Просто там где проверяется с помощью preg_match, есть еще код, который не нужно выполнять при $a == $b.

Comment: Так все правильно, просто уже в блоке `{}` сделайте уточнение

    if ( ( preg_match("/^все/", $pere) ) || ( $a == $b ) ) {
      /* общие */
      if ($a == $b) { /* только для $a==$b */ }
      }

Можете еще условия вынести:

    $con1 = (bool) preg_match("/^все/", $pere);
    $con2 = ($a==$b);
    $con3 = true; /* еще какое-то условие */
    if ($con1 || $con2) {
      /* общее */
      if ($con1) {
        /* для preg_match */
        } elseif ($con2) {
        /* для $a==$b */
        } else {
        /* для $con3 */
        }
      }

Comment: @nick777, Так напишите весь код, который вам надо организовать! А то мы вечность будет гадать, что-же вам надо, а то и не одну...

Answer (score 0):

А вам не приходило в голову просто вынести повторяемый участок кода в отдельную функцию?